# Web Services exposed by url

Tags: web-services, web-api

Lets take some random internet site which i am not aware of any API it exposes for it's web services if there are any , is there a way to query that URL for exposed web services ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: i didn't try any thing i don't know much about web services 
i know how to work with WCF services that expose WSDL .

now lets say i came across some site and i don't know if it exposes any web services , how can i find out ?

Comment: Uhm, you want to go any random website and "query" it for software-accessible endpoint? This sounds like hacking to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789856/how-do-i-discover-restful-web-services

Comment: @user16764  Old-style (non-REST) web services could be queried with [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language).  There is a counterpart to WSDL for REST services called [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language), but most REST services don't provide it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that he intends to "query" the front-facing, user-accessible homepage for unadvertised web service URLs, not to start at an advertised web service URL and check for other endpoints. Never mind that the normal way to "discover" whether a website provides an API is to search on Google for developer sites like developer.paypal.com.

Comment: @user16764 RobertHarvey had it right i wan't to discover services that the site exposes ( to anyone ) not to hack it.

Comment: But still , how can i discover WSDL or WADL services of a certaine web site

Comment: @eranotzap documentation for humans specifying the location.

Comment: @MichaelT what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined way to "query" a site about any web services it might offer. Typically, if the site wants you to be able to query it, the method to do so will be clearly indicated (perhaps find a "Developers" link on the site). Otherwise, the site probably doesn't want you to query it.